# Angular window height and width

Tags: angular

In multiple components I have same methods for style recalculation. For example, I use `HomeMainComponent` to render my home page. It nested in `MainComponent -> CoreComponent -> HomeComponent -> HomeMainComponent`:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main[app-home-main]',
  templateUrl: './home-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home-main.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeMainComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  mainSectionStyles = {};

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.onInitAndOnResize(null);
  }

  onInitAndOnResize(e) {
    const resultedStyles: any = {
      'box-shadow': 'none',
      'min-height.px': 0,
      'padding-bottom.px': 0,
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
      const starsBlock = document.getElementById('stars');

      resultedStyles.boxShadow = this.getBoxShadow();

      let minHeight = this.getWindowHeigh();
      if (navbar) {
        minHeight = minHeight - navbar.offsetHeight;
      }
      if (starsBlock) {
        resultedStyles['padding-bottom.px'] = starsBlock.offsetHeight;
      }
      resultedStyles['min-height.px'] = minHeight;

      this.mainSectionStyles = Object.assign({}, resultedStyles);
    }, 300);
  }

  private getWindowHeigh() {
    return (
      document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
      window.innerHeight ||
      document.body.clientHeight
    );
  }

  private getBoxShadow() {
    const windowWidth =
      window.innerWidth ||
      document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
      document.body.clientWidth;
    const shadowWidth = windowWidth / 3;
    return 'inset 0 0 ' + shadowWidth + 'px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  }
}
```

As you can see I use method `onInitAndOnResize` to recalculate styles object, that I use in `ngStyle`. Also I copied this methods for five other pages in my app. I believe that I do wrong and there is more true way to do this.

Comment: why on earth are you doing it? why you dont have a normal class/use same style for all  in your sass/less file?

Comment: @Talg123 because I have three levels of `z-index` in same html block, that can't be configured with normal css.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, with your code my suggestions are:

1. use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) for resize

```
    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    
    onResize(event) {
      event.target.innerWidth;
    }
```

2. As you are using typescript avoid type any, create an interface
3. Please use angular way to get element, take a look at [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)
4. If you want share it, you can export the function to avoid copy-paste to each component

Finally, it's confused why u need setTimeout to update your style, css may be help non ?

Comment: Ok. So simple question. How to get `window height` with `angular way`?

Comment: it's correct in your code to get window heigh, I think he was talking about this line  `const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');` 
these suggestions are greate, and you can also share your function by service @MikitaMelnikau

Answer (score 0):

All thank you for answers. I solved it with directive:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  HostListener,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'section[#section-bricks]',
})
export class BrickWallStylesDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setStylesForBrickBlock();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  onResize() {
    this.setStylesForBrickBlock();
  }

  private setStylesForBrickBlock() {
    this.setDefaultStyles();

    setTimeout(() => {
      const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
      const starsBlock = document.getElementById('stars');

      this.el.nativeElement.style.boxShadow = this.getBoxShadow();

      let minHeight = this.getWindowHeigh();
      if (navbar) {
        minHeight = minHeight - navbar.offsetHeight;
      }
      this.el.nativeElement.style.minHeight = `${minHeight}px`;

      if (starsBlock) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.paddingBottom = `${starsBlock.offsetHeight}px`;
      }
    }, 300);
  }

  private setDefaultStyles() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.boxShadow = 'none';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.minHeight = '0px';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.paddingBottom = '0px';
  }

  private getWindowHeigh() {
    return (
      document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
      window.innerHeight ||
      document.body.clientHeight
    );
  }

  private getWindowWidth() {
    return (
      document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
      window.innerWidth ||
      document.body.clientWidth
    );
  }

  private getBoxShadow() {
    const windowWidth = this.getWindowWidth();
    const shadowWidth = windowWidth / 3;
    return 'inset 0 0 ' + shadowWidth + 'px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  }
}
```